# React-Native-WebView is not showing any website

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview

I just installed react-native-webview in react native . After that I trying to display the website , but its loading .

Here is my code

```
    import React from "react";
    import { View ,Text} from 'react-native';
    import {WebView} from 'react-native-webview';
    const WebViewComponent = () =\>{
    return \<WebView source={{ uri: 'https://reactnative.dev/' }} style={{ flex: 1 }} /\>;
    }
    export default WebViewComponent;
```

I just tried to display the website but its not displaying . Is there any extra dependency required to display the WebView or I just screwed up my code.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided looks correct. It should display the reactnative.dev website in a WebView component. However, there are a few things you can check if the website is not loading:

Check if the react-native-webview package is installed correctly. Make sure you've installed the package using npm or yarn and that the installation completed successfully without any errors.

Check if you've granted the necessary permissions to access the internet. In your AndroidManifest.xml file, make sure you have the following permission:
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Check the console logs for any errors. If there are any errors, try to debug them and fix them.

here is code that will check if website loads:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";

const WebViewComponent = () => {
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);

  const handleError = (error) => {
    console.log("Error loading website", error);
    setIsError(true);
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      {isError ? (
        <Text style={{ textAlign: "center", marginTop: 16 }}>
          Error loading website.
        </Text>
      ) : (
        <WebView
          source={{ uri: "https://reactnative.dev/" }}
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          onError={handleError}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default WebViewComponent;
```